# Showing and Hiding Horizontal ScrollView on Button Click in Place of Button on Same Screen

Tags: android, android-layout, button, scroll, scrollview

I am new to android development so need some help. I want to show horizontal scroll view after the button is clicked which is associated with the scroll view. I can't figure it out that how to show & hide scroll view on same place as of button on same application screen.

E.g: The button name is Show Emoticons and when I click the button I want a ScrollView containing images to appear and when I select an image from it the ScrollView hides. ScrollView will contain ImageView which will contain image.

Any sort of help in this regard will be highly appreciated.